# Discord.py bot returning multiple messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi O'm having a problem with this simple little python discord bot module. Whenever I use command, it seems to be returning 4 or 5 responses even though it's coded to only return one. I'm I overlooking something, Is there a simple fix for this?

Here is the code I'm working with

```
import discord
import os
import logging as log
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Forbidden, HTTPException

from .utils.dataIO import dataIO
from .utils import checks


import asyncio

class lurkout:
"""
add roles to new members after x amount of time
"""

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def huntlurkers(self, ctx, *_):
    """Look for lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid)

    for member in server.members:
        lurker_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Lurker")
        if lurker_role not in member.roles:
            await self.bot.say("No lurkers seen within the last 3 days.")
        else:
            await self.check_roles(serverid, member)
            await self.bot.say("Success! You have manually added the Lurker role to those who haven't received a members role in 3 days.")
            return


@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def kicklurkers(self, ctx, *_):
    """Mass kick lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid)

    for member in server.members:
        lurker_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Lurker")
        if lurker_role not in member.roles:
            await self.bot.send_message("There are no lurkers to kick.")
        else:
            if lurker_role in member.roles:
                await self.check_lurkers(serverid, member)
                await self.bot.send_message("Kicked some lurkers :D.")
                return


async def check_roles(self, serverid, member: discord.Member, *_):

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid)
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Lurker")
    members_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Members")

    for member in server.members:
         if member.joined_at + timedelta(days=3) <= datetime.today():
            if members_role not in member.roles:    
                try:
                    await self.bot.add_roles(member, lurker_role)
                    log.info("[SUCCESS] Changing role of "+str(member)+" succeeded")
                except (Forbidden, HTTPException) as e:
                    log.info("[FAILURE] Changing role of "+str(member)+" failed")


async def check_lurkers(self, serverid, member: discord.Member, *_):

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid)
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Lurker")
    members_role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Members")

    for member in list(self.bot.get_all_members()):
         if member.joined_at + timedelta(days=0) <= datetime.today():
            if lurker_role in member.roles:    
                try:
                    await self.bot.kick(member)
                    log.info("[SUCCESS] Changing role of "+str(member)+" succeeded")
                except (Forbidden, HTTPException) as e:
                    log.info("[FAILURE] Changing role of "+str(member)+" failed")


async def check_day(self):
    tomorrow = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
    midnight = datetime(year=tomorrow.year, month=tomorrow.month, 
                    day=tomorrow.day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

    await asyncio.sleep((midnight - datetime.now()).seconds)
    print("About to start")
    while self is self.bot.get_cog("check_roles"):

        await self.autoaddrole_update()

        await asyncio.sleep(86400) # Wait 24 hours



def setup(bot):
    q = lurkout(bot)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(q.check_day())
    bot.add_cog(q)
```

The issue persists with the `async def huntlurkers(self, ctx, *_):` and `async def kicklurkers(self, ctx, *_):` commands and the `await` statements return about 4 times.

Edit:

Here is the edit I have attempted to put in to my code the issue I get is local variable 'member' referenced before assignment

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def kicklurkers(self, ctx, *_):
    """Mass kick lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid) # This could probably be ctx.message.server
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Lurker")
    member_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Members")
    any_lurkers = False
    if member_role not in member.roles:
        for member in server.members:
            if lurker_role in member.roles:
                if member.joined_at + timedelta(days=3) <= datetime.today():
                    await self.bot.kick(member)
                    any_lurkers=True
            if any_lurkers:
                await self.bot.say("Kicked all lurkers!")
            else:
                await self.bot.say("No lurkers to kick!")
```

Comment: Your `if member_role not in member.roles` check should be inside the `for` loop, and the `if any_lurkers:` check should be outside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands loop over the members of a server. *For each member*, if they are not a lurker you send a message. If they are a lurker, you do something with that member, then stop processing.  From the messages you're sending, it seems that you instead want to process all the users, then print one of the two messages depending on whether or not you discover any lurkers.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def kicklurkers(self, ctx, *_):
    """Mass kick lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid) # This could probably be ctx.message.server
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Lurker")
    member_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Members")
    any_lurkers = False
    for member in server.members:
        if member_role not in member.roles and lurker_role in member.roles:
            if member.joined_at + timedelta(days=3) <= datetime.today():
                await self.bot.kick(member)
                any_lurkers=True
    if any_lurkers:
        await self.bot.say("Kicked all lurkers!")
    else:
        await self.bot.say("No lurkers to kick!")
```

I don't understand what your `check_lurkers` coroutine is trying to accomplish. Is it to check if a specific `Member` is a lurker, to kick all the lurkers from a server, or to change their roles?

Comment: The check_lurkers coroutine is trying to accomplish how long the member has been on the server before applying the lurker role. :)

Comment: So why are you calling it in `kicklurkers`, and why does it loop through all the members the bot can see?

Comment: Hey @PatrickHaugh 

Thanks for your reply I have made an edit to your answer showing how I have tried to implement this the issue with this is I'm wanting to do the following task:

Kick user after they have joined the server but check if they **don't** have the member_role and check if they **do** have the lurker_role. 

In my edit I get the error `local variable 'member' referenced before assignment` however defined as member_role but I don't want to add it as a signature otherwise that will give me a <member> after command.

Comment: @ShanJameson I've edited my answer to reflect the changes you should make to your new code.

Comment: Thank you for this I have encountered an issue `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` would you suggest `for member in list(self.bot.get_all_members()):` or will this send too many awaits?

Comment: You can loop over `list(server.members)` instead.  I would avoid `get_all_members` simply because it includes every member a bot can see, including those on other servers.  It's impossible for those members to have the two roles you specify, so the checks are meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your again @PatrickHaugh I will check your answer to mark this answered. Have a great day!